# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, web-service

Aguém poderia, por favor, me ajudar e dizer o que está errado?

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//CONECTANDO O APP À INTERNET
HashMap<Integer,View> views = new HashMap<Integer,View>();
Assincrona assinc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    //CONECTANDO O APP À INTERNET
    views.put(R.id.progressBar, findViewById(R.id.progressBar));
    views.put(R.id.txtServidor, findViewById(R.id.txtServidor));
    views.put(R.id.etProduto, findViewById(R.id.etProduto));
    views.put(R.id.etValor, findViewById(R.id.etValor));

    assinc=new Assincrona(3, 3, true,views,this);//

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();


        }
    });
}

//CONECTANDO O APP À INTERNET
public void conectar(View v){



    if(NetSource.isConected(this)){
        ViewMap.setVisibility(views, R.id.progressBar, true);

        Log.i("LOG", "conectado");

        assinc.play();

        Log.i("LOG", "depois do play");

    }

    else{

        Log.i("LOG", "sem conexão");

        ViewMap.setContentTextView(views, R.id.txtServidor, "Sem conexão");
        ViewMap.setVisibility(views, R.id.progressBar, false);
    }

}//


}



/**
* Created by Administrador on 21/10/2015.
* CONECTANDO A APP À INTERNET
*/

public class Assincrona extends offUIImplementation {


public Assincrona(int timeout, int tentativas, boolean askRetry,
                  HashMap<Integer, View> views, Context context) {
    super(timeout, tentativas, askRetry, views, context);

    configRetry("Falha de conexao!", "Tentar novamente?", "sim", "não");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public GenericAsync configTypeAsync() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Requisição();
}

@Override
public void fail(GenericAsync arg0) {

    setContentTextView(R.id.txtServidor, "Conexao falida!");
    setVisibility(R.id.progressBar, false);
}

@Override
public void sucess(GenericAsync arg0) {

    Log.i("LOG", "sucess");
    setContentTextView(R.id.txtServidor, arg0.getReturn());
    setVisibility(R.id.progressBar, false);

}





public class Requisição extends GenericAsync {

    @Override
    public String task(String... arg0) {



        RequestParameters[] parametros = {

                new RequestParameters("action", "1")
                //new RequestParameters("produto",        getContentEditText(R.id.etProduto)),
                //new RequestParameters("valor", getContentEditText(R.id.etValor))
        };





        return NetSource.sendGet("http://lascode.esy.es/webservice.php",
                parametros).toString();


        //return NetSource.sendGet("http://lascode.esy.es/webservice.php",
                //parametros).toString().replace("<br/>","\n");

    }

}

 /*public class Requisição extends GenericAsync{

    @Override
    public String task(String... arg0) {

        RequestParameters[] parametros = {new           
  RequestParameters("nome","andre"),
                new RequestParameters("apelido","figas")};

        return NetSource.sendPost("http://192.168.0.18/android/nome.php/",
                parametros).toString().replace("<br/>","\n");
    }



}*/

}


//Conteúdo do xml:
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etProduto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="*Produto"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etValor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="*Valor"
    android:inputType="number" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Conteudo do Servidor"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/txtServidor" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cadastrar novo produto"
    android:id="@+id/btn_txt_net"
    android:onClick="conectar"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e coloque o código devidamente formatado

Comment: Nesse caso, terei de colocar mais uma pergunta: como colocar o código devidamente formatado aqui?

Comment: É só usar indentação de no mínimo 4 espaços. E outra coisa, adicione à pergunta também o log do erro exibido no LogCat (de onde você copiou o título da pergunta).

Comment: Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) como formatar texto e código.

Comment: O erro que consta no log é exatamento o que foi colocado no título.

Comment: @CarlosXimendes Só esse erro é pouco para investigar o problema. Precisamos do _stack trace_ completo (incluindo a exceção que foi gerada, em qual linha do arquivo foi que ocorreu, e precisamos que você aponte no código qual é essa linha).

Comment: Não remete a nenhuma linha do projeto. O aplicativo é executado normalmente, até que quando clico no botão para criar dados no banco de dados remoto, e aparece a mensagem "O aplicativo parou!". No log, aparece a exceção que está no título.